# How to use RegExp in a location path on my nginx config?

Tags: regex, nginx, next.js

I have a navigation route that looks like:

`/book/bookname-1234/`

I have an API route to purchase the book at:

`/book/1234/purchase`

For the navigation route, I want my Nextjs server to handle it, but the API route I want be handled by our python server.

In my nginx config I have defined Nextjs routes with the catchall going to python.

For the navigation route, I have it set as:

```
location ~ /book/^[a-z]+(?:-[0-9]+)$ {
   try_files $uri @nextjs;
}
```

I have also tried putting double quotes around the `"/book/^[a-z]+(?:-[0-9]+)$"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the url, you can use:

```
/book/[a-z]+-[0-9]+/$
```

If you want to reuse the capture group values, you can use 2 capture groups.

Note that there is an ending `/` in the example string, and using `^` denotes the end of the string.

```
/book/a-z]+-[0-9]+/$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IYO7tb/1)

Then you could use the 2 capture groups followed by the word `purchase` to get `/book/1234/purchase`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect. I really appreciate the link with demo. The explanation helped me understand a bit more what was happening